# I want to install Drupal on my windows system, I already have wamp installed should I install aquiadrupal?

Tags: drupal-7

A tutorial suggest the best way to install Drupal is to install the acquia drupal stack but I already have wamp installed.  I don't know if I should remove wamp( I don't know how best to do that) or have them both installed or what. I currently have mysql 5.5.24 and php 5.3.13.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal is a web-application composed of PHP scripts that access MySQL. WAMP is a platform that runs PHP scripts using Apache and MySQL.

So it's up to you if you want to use a general WAMP stack such as Xampp, WampServer, or Wamp-Developer Pro, create a website with it, and install Drupal in that website... Or if you want to use a specifically tailored WAMP distribution that already comes with Drupal pre-installed.

Both have their upsides and downsides. Using Acquia Drupal stack might be quicker, but there will be more general options available otherwise with Wamp-Developer or Xampp.

One is geared for a very specific use, the others for many uses.